# STL set_symmetric_difference usage

Tags: c++, stl

I was solving a programming problem, which wants to find the SYMMETRIC DIFFERENCE between two sets. I have solved it using STL's `set_symmetric_difference`. I am given two `vector<int>s`, `A` and `B`:

> A = {342,654,897,312,76,23,78}
>
> B = {21,43,87,98,23,756,897,234,645,876,123}

Sould return (correct answer):

> { 21,43,76,78,87,98,123,234,312,342,645,654,756,876 }

But I get:

> { 21,43,76,78,87,98,123,234,312,342,645,65,756,876}

What is the problem ? Here is my code:

```
sort(A.begin(), A.end());
sort(B.begin(), B.end());
// allocate the smallest size of A,B as maximum size
vector<int> c(A.size() < B.size() ? B.size() : A.size());
vector<int>::iterator i;
i = set_symmetric_difference(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), c.begin());
return vector<int>(c.begin(), i);
```

**NOTE:**
I get correct answers for the rest of examples. This example only gives me this wrong answer.

I have tested it in Visual Studio, and got an error message: "Iterator not incrementable"

Comment: The only difference, I see between the expected and the real answer is: `654` in the expected and `65` in the returned, **but I don't see 65 in the sets at all**. So, I guess `65` is a typo and it should be `654`, right? In that case, what is the difference?

Comment: @KirilKirov The answer should be ordered in ascending oreder. I don't know why does this `65` appear there

Comment: Because you have initialized the `vector`s wrong? Check their initialization again and see if there's `65` in some of them. And print here the sorted vectors, just in case.

Comment: It is a problem with the vector's initialization. A solution with an empty vector and push_back seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the initialization of vector `c`. The logic is slightly wrong in that the maximum size of the output range *could* be as large as the sum of the two input ranges. Since you don't know the size a priori, you could be better off by starting with an empty output vector, and using push_back with an [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) instead:

```
sort(A.begin(), A.end());
sort(B.begin(), B.end());
std::vector<int> c;
set_symmetric_difference(A.begin(), A.end(), 
                         B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
return c;
```

This produces

> 21 43 76 78 87 98 123 234 312 342 645 654 756 876

Answer (score 3):

When I run your code, I get an exception from the vector iterator not be incrementable. I think the problem lies here:

`vector c(A.size() < B.size() ? B.size() : A.size());`

I changed it to:

`vector c(A.size() + B.size());`

and ran it with no exceptions. I also get the same numbers as what you wrote (the correct ones).

Comment: That initializes the output vector to the maximum possible size of the output, so you should see a bunch of zeroes after the correct sequence.

Comment: In memory they would be, but in the output I didn't get any zeroes when I looped through the resulting vector. When the resulting vector is initialized, it doesn't include the zeroes because of the way the set_symmetric_difference function works. But your answer is better as it does save memory.

Comment: Ah yes, that is because the original returns a trimmed down version of `c`, whereas mine returns a copy of `c`.