# How to compare 2 vectors and create a separate vector based on the comparison

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

i'm looking at creating an algorithm that will compare 2 vectors (`v1`,`v2`), and create a new vector `v3` that will hold the values not shared between `v1` and `v2`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(int args[])
{
vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
vector<int> v2 = { 1,2,6 };
vector<int> v3; //V3 should equal = {3,4,5,7,8,9}.

return 0;
}
```

The vectors will always be sorted.

Comment: Are `v1` and `v2` necessarily sorted? If so, you can probably get away with using [`std::mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) in a loop to find which values are not in both vectors.

Comment: Can you assume they'll be sorted?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 
yes, the 2 vectors will always be sorted, i'll take a look at std::mismatch now.

Comment: While sorting makes things easier, it's not necessary. Just copy the first vector and for each copied value, search for the exact same value in v2. If that value is present - delete that value from v3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [STL set\_symmetric\_difference usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373583/stl-set-symmetric-difference-usage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, as in your example, the ranges are sorted then you can use [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference).  It will return all elements that are not shared between the two ranges.  Using you example you would use

```
std::set_symmetric_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));
```

So putting it all together we have

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1,2,6 };
    std::vector<int> v3; //V3 should equal = {3,4,5,7,8,9}.

    std::set_symmetric_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(v3));

    for (auto e : v3)
        std::cout << e << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 4 5 7 8 9
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dcdf6a5767383d9)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect!
This is exactly what i needed, thanks very much.

Comment: Would `std::set_difference` be more appropriate? Otherwise, elements in `v2` not already in `v1` would be included in the result.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It might be.  I need to check with the OP

Comment: @SamRobinson if `v2` had `10` in it would you want that in the output result or no?

Comment: @NathanOliver i'm trying to create a sudoku solving algorithm, meaning that only numbers 1-9 will appear. I will however bare this in mind for future projects. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to trouble  and add new answer here. NathanOliver has given precise answer. 
 But for fun if I had to write my own function to implement this, I tried it on arrays instead of vector, (for changing code for vector will be trivial task).

Adding my code snippet here.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int arr1[]={2,3,6,10};
int arr2[]={3,5,7,9,10};

int result[10];
int result_size=0;

void getUncommonValues(int *arr1, int size1, int *arr2, int size2){
    if ( (size1 == 0) && (size2 == 0) )
        return;

    if( size1 == 0){
        result_size=size2;
        for (int i=0; i < size2; i++)
            result[i] = arr2[i];
    }

    if (size2 == 0){
        result_size=size1;
        for (int i=0; i < size1; i++)
            result[i] = arr1[i];
    }

    int i1=0, i2=0;
    while (size1 > i1){
        if ( arr1[i1] < arr2[i2]){
            result[result_size++] = arr1[i1++];
        } else{
            if ( arr2[i2] < arr1[i1] )
                result[result_size++] = arr2[i2++];
            else{
                i1++; i2++;
            }
        }
        if ( i2 == size2 ){
            for ( ; i1 < size1; i1++)
                result[result_size++] = arr1[i1];
        }
    }

    for ( ; i2 < size2 ; i2++){
        result[result_size++] = arr2[i2];
    }
}

int main(){
    getUncommonValues(arr1,sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int), arr2,sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int));
    for (int i =0; i<result_size; i++)
        cout << result[i] <<" ,";

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note : here the result is stored in global array and has fixed size. 
   This can be resolved in vector directly.