# Generating difference of two object arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on an interesting problem at the moment where I have a C++ program which uses two arrays of objects, of possibly different lengths which may contain some, all, or none of the same objects at the same or different indices.

I want to create a list (keeping it data structure agnostic for the moment) of pairs of these objects that represents a diff of these arrays. The reason for this is that the list will be passed to a UI control that expects the data in this format.

If an object is in the first array, but not the other, then that qualifies as an insertion as you would expect in diff or another comparison tool, so I want to add that object to my list without a corresponding object from the second array. The opposite is true if I find an object in the second array that isn't in the first.

For objects that are either the same or not insertions/deletions, we set the first and second object of each entry in the list to the value in the first and second array accordingly.

I've been investigating various diff algorithms such as the ones outlined here http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2006/01/16/comparing-strings-an-analysis-of-diff-algorithms/
However I get the impression they may be overkill for what I am trying to do. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful, thanks.

Comment: If your sets are sorted or if they may be sorted you may be able to use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to compare 2 vectors and create a separate vector based on the comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099696/how-to-compare-2-vectors-and-create-a-separate-vector-based-on-the-comparison)

Comment: The arrays contain objects which encapusulate strings from text files and other formats along with a load of metadata for each string. They cannot be sorted as we need to preserve the order of the strings.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a specific question. It's more akin to an open-ended request for recommendations.